# What part of speech is 'stumble' in this sentence?

Tags: sense-verbs, syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles

I saw this sentence somewhere: 'This episode sees the heroine stumble upon a body.'. I know 'stumble' is a verb, but which part of the verb is being used here?  I don't think I really know how to parse any part of this sentence after the word 'heroine'.

Comment: Bare Infinitive form!

Comment: He saw her trip over a body.

Comment: Is it a relative clause (relating to something the heroine does)?

Comment: It's the plain form, sometimes called the infinitive or base form. "See" is a catenative verb and the infinitival clause "stumble upon a body" is its catenative complement. The intervening NP "the heroine" is direct object of "see".

Comment: Yes. It's what's called an infinitive complement clause. It's a special variety because _see_ is a sense verb, and they have unusual and extensive syntax. One of the specialities is that the ordinary infinitive marker _to_ is omitted in clauses after non-volitional sense verbs (_I saw him leave_ but not *_I saw him to leave_). The NP intervening between _see_ and _stumble_ is the subject of _stumble_, Raised to object position following _see_. This sentence could be parsed with the whole clause as object of _see_, or with _the heroine_ as the object. Raising does both.

Answer (score 1):

> *This episode sees the heroine stumble upon a body.*

"See" is a catenative verb, and the subordinate infinitival clause "stumble upon a body" is its catenative complement.

Syntactically "the heroine" is object of "see", but semantically it relates only to the subordinate *stumble* clause, not to "see". "The heroine" is thus called a 'raised object' because the verb it relates to syntactically is higher in the constituent structure than the one it relates to semantically.

The term 'catenative' comes from the Latin word for "chain", which is appropriate here since "see" and "stumble" do indeed form a chain of two verbs, in this case separated only by the NP "the heroine" and hence called a complex catenative construction.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Yes. It's what's called an infinitive complement clause. It's a special variety because *see* is a sense verb, and they have unusual and extensive syntax. One of the specialities is that the ordinary infinitive marker *to* is omitted in clauses after non-volitional sense verbs (*I saw him leave* but not **I saw him to leave*). The NP intervening between *see* and *stumble* is the subject of *stumble*, Raised to object position following *see*. This sentence could be parsed with the whole clause as object of *see*, or with *the heroine* as the object. Raising does both.